# Common Lispのdefstructのスロットの:read-onlyオプションについて

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

defstructのスロットに:read-onlyオプションを付けますが、SBCL等ではスロットに書き込めてしまいます。
他の処理系では、セッターを定義しないことで書き込みをしにくくしているようですが、
なにかもっと良い方法はないのでしょうか。

```
(defstruct foo (x nil :read-only t) y z)


(setf (foo-x (make-foo :x 9)) 8)
;sbcl =>  8
;!> allegro: `(SETF FOO-X)' is not fbound
;!> ecl: The function (SETF FOO-X) is undefined.
;!> clisp: FUNCALL: undefined function |(SETF COMMON-LISP-USER:FOO-X)|


;; ※ANSI CL仕様外
(setf (slot-value (make-foo :x 9) 'x) 8)
;=>  8
```

エラーを出すようセッターを定義する位しかないのでしょうか。

```
(defun (setf foo-x) (val foo)
  (declare (ignore val))
  (error "~S: attempt to write a readonly slot: X" foo))


;; ※ANSI CL仕様外
(defmethod (setf c2mop:slot-value-using-class)
           (val
            (class (eql (find-class 'foo)))
            (obj foo)
            (slotd
             (eql
              (find 'x (c2mop:class-slots (find-class 'foo))
               :key #'c2mop:slot-definition-name))))
  (error "~S: attempt to write a readonly slot: X" obj))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sbcl1.2.1では治っているようです。

```
; SLIME 2014-08-01
CL-USER> (defstruct foo (x nil :read-only t) y z)
FOO
CL-USER> (defvar foo (make-foo :x 9))
FOO
CL-USER> (setf (foo-x foo) 8)
; in: SETF (FOO-X FOO)
;     (FUNCALL #'(SETF FOO-X) #:NEW1940 #:FOO1941)
; ==>
;   (SB-C::%FUNCALL #'(SETF FOO-X) #:NEW1940 #:FOO1941)
; 
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: (SETF FOO-X)
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     (SETF FOO-X)
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
; Evaluation aborted on #<UNDEFINED-FUNCTION (SETF FOO-X) {1004B1EF03}>.
CL-USER> (lisp-implementation-version)
"1.2.1"
CL-USER> (lisp-implementation-type)
"SBCL"
```

ただし、スロット直アクセスは出来るようです。

```
CL-USER> (setf (slot-value foo 'x) 9)
9
```

これを防ぐには、スロット名をインターンされていないシンボル `#:x` にしましょう。
どのパッケージにも属さないシンボルなので、後の参照を不可能にすることが出来ます。

```
CL-USER> (defstruct bar (#:x nil :read-only t) y z)
BAR
CL-USER> (defvar bar (make-bar :x 9))
BAR
CL-USER> (setf (slot-value bar '#:x) 7)
; Evaluation aborted on #<SIMPLE-ERROR "~@<When attempting to ~A, the slot ~S is missing from the ~
CL-USER> (setf (slot-value bar 'x) 7)
; Evaluation aborted on #<SIMPLE-ERROR "~@<When attempting to ~A, the slot ~S is missing from the ~
          object ~S.~@:>" {1005C844E3}>.
```

一方、アクセサ名は現在のパッケージにインターンされるので、参照することが出来ます。
このことは、http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defstr.htm の :conc-name セクションにて明記されています。

```
CL-USER> (bar-x bar)
9
```

Comment: なるほどSBCLの動作はバグだったようですね。

defstructでは、セッターを定義しない程度でスロットのread-ontyを実現していて、そこを重視するならクラスを使えという感じなのかもしれませんね。